# Mocking a Controller that adding user via JSON Post

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to create a mock controller but I keep getting error with Capturing argument. It say wanted but not invoked. I'm still confused with Mockito and Junit and how it should properly works.

> ControllerMock

```
@Test
public void testAddUserController() throws Exception {

    JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("username", "User 1");
        jsonObject.put("email", "user1@email.com");
        jsonObject.put("password", "password123");
        jsonObject.put("address", "Address 1");
        jsonObject.put("age", 12);
    userArray.put(jsonObject);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(BASE_URL + "/users").content(toString()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1))
            .addUser(userCaptor.capture(), emailCaptor.capture(), passwordCaptor.capture(), addressCaptor.capture(), ageCaptor.capture());

    Assert.assertEquals("User 1", userCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("user1@email.com", emailCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("password123", passwordCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("Address 1", addressCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("12", ageCaptor.getValue());

}
```

> UserService

```
boolean addUser(String username, String email, String password, String address, Integer age);
```

> UserServiceImpl

```
@Override
public boolean addUser(String username, String email, String password, String address, Integer age) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsernameAndEmail(username, email);
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUsername(username);
        user1.setEmail(email);
        user1.setPassword(password);
        user1.setAddress(address);
        user1.setAge(age);
        user1.setIsActive(true);
        userRepository.save(user1);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a junit test by `@Test` and use `Mockito` for mocking HttpResponse

```
InputStream jsonResponse = createJsonResponse();   
Mockito.when(mHttpClientMock.execute(Mockito.isA(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(mHttpResponseMock);
    Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mStatusLineMock);
    Mockito.when(mStatusLineMock.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    Mockito.when(mHttpResponseMock.getEntity()).thenReturn(mHttpEntityMock);
    Mockito.when(mHttpEntityMock.getContent()).thenReturn(jsonResponse);
```

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/how-test-rest-api-junit